# Total weight my slab can carry

Tags: beam, slab

I have a stilt and first floor .It have size of 10'x18'. It is concrete slab of 4" and it doesn't have reinforced. It has been supported by steel beam and column. Now I have a table of marble which weighs around 1.5 tons . Can you please suggest will the slab be able to hold the weight with calculation

Comment: If this slab is in the air(supported by beam), 1.5 tons does not sound good.  It should be okay if the slab is supported completely on the ground.

Comment: What's the spacing between columns and beams? How are those supported?

Answer (score 1):

4" slab **unreinforced,** on beams and columns? Good luck with that.

Perhaps if you could set it directly on a beam, but you'd have to *get it there* without breaking the floor first, which seems unlikely.

Comment: 1.5 tons does sound hard on the back.  Even 1 ton was hard, but at least it was in 25 bags.

Comment: If it was on the ground, it's not too difficult, as even poor concrete is typically 2500-3000 PSI compressive strength, so a couple of square inches would handle the load directly, and it would be spread to a larger area of soil below. Unreinforced concrete that's not formed into an arch (where all loads become compressive loads) is a very dubious thing to not support directly on the ground, as its tensile strength is poor - that's what reinforcing steel is all about.